# Tridion 2009 SP1: Opening Component via Page metadata opens Shared Item without showing dialog?

Tags: tridion

In SDL Tridion 2009 SP1, I am using Page Metadata with Component Links to set some featured media, SEO data, etc for Pages. The problem is when the editor clicks the "open" button to edit this from the Page, the Shared Item is opened at the current Publication in read only mode. What we need is for the Shared Item dialog to be displayed as per opening a Component Presentation so that we can edit the parent item.

Is there a way to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL have now produced a Hotfix for this issue:

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CM_2009.1.81021_tcm89-20623.zip (log in required)

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a hot fix for this. I will try to find the number.

**UPDATE**

It seems I was wrong -  The issue I am thinking of was for SDL Tridion 2011 and solved with hotfix CM_2011.0.1.73971 at https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011/index.aspx - I guess it is possible the issue came from 2009 SP1.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I had a quick look through but didn't see one that looked like it was the one.

Comment: I just looked through them too, and I don't see it either. I think your best bet here is to open a ticket with SDL Customer Support. I am pretty sure this is a defect. But the issue I am thinking of  was for SDL Tridion 2011 and solved with hotfix CM_2011.0.1.73971 at https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011/index.aspx I guess it is possible the issue came from 2009 SP1

Comment: Thanks Chris, I had already opened with SDL but you were quicker :-) I will post back with their response.